# Traverse a xml tree recursively and push element value into custom class

Tags: c#, xml, linq, recursion, traversal

Whitin a "units" element can be many "unit" elements which again have a "units" element.

I want to write the unitName of each unit into a custom class with prop UnitName AND the unitName of the previous/parent unit into the prop ParentUnitName.

I am also unsure what type of data the recursive method should return... best would be a List with a flat list.

How would you do that?

```
<units>
  <unit>
    <unitName>Test05</unitName>    
    <units>
      <unit>
        <unitName>Test03</unitName>        
        <units>
          <unit>
            <unitName>Test04</unitName>           
            <units>
              <unit>
                <unitName>Test07</unitName>                
                <units>
                  <unit>
                    <unitName>Test01</unitName>                    
                  </unit>
                </units>
              </unit>
            </units>
          </unit>
        </units>
      </unit>
    </units>
  </unit>
</units>
```

Comment: Are you using XmlDocument or XmlReader? What have you tried? Where did it fail? I would probably use a method like void ReadUnits(XmlNode node, String parentUnitName, List<CustomClass> list) that will call it self recusively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [XDocument class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx).

It has a variety of methods available to help with parsing Xml easily. In your case it would look something like:

```
var xdoc = new XDocument(xmlString);
foreach(XElement node in xdoc.Descendants("unitName"))
{
  AddToList(node.value);
}
```

This will iterate through all `unitName` elements in the xml document and you can do whatever you want with them.

Edit: Changed xdoc.Descendants to xdoc.Elements, so it works recursively now and yields the expected results.

Comment: ... and it is slow, veeeeery slow.

Comment: @Fischermaen: It's not that much slower and until it's an identified bottleneck I wouldn't use XmlSerializer only for its speed.

Comment: it does not work recursively with elements because you do not check in the foreach further node.Elements("unitName")

Comment: What I meant was, that the ````xdoc.Descendants```` will traverse the xml in it's entirety and return all 5 ````unitName```` nodes in the document in the right order (5,3,4,7,1).

Comment: what i want is to iterate through each unit and from this point i want to be able to access a previous node

Comment: @Darcara Using your method, how can I reference the parent? From Test03 I want to get Test05

Comment: There are several ways, have a look at the [XNode class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.aspx). You have .Parent for the direct parent node, .Ancestors() with the ability to search for "higher" nodes and .NodesBeforeSelf to get a collection of all ancestors. Plus there are a variety of other methods as well, that help you navigate in any direction (e.g. NextNode for sibling nodes)

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer writing a class in this way:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("unit")]
public class Unit
{
    [XmlArray("units")]
    [XmlArrayItem("unit")]
    public Unit[] Units { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("unitName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then serialize / deserialize it with XmlSerializer.